# What is a group of determiners called?

Tags: terminology, determiners

Verbs, auxiliaries and modals constitute the verb group (Vgp).

Is there an official term used to describe a [group of determiners] (pre-, central-, post-) that pre-modify the noun in the NP? In the following examples, more than one determiner pre-modifies the noun.

[My three] cats
[Both the] cats
[All the many] cats

We can't call it a determiner phrase because according to the DP-hypothesis, the determiner phrase is an alternative to the NP whereby the determiner heads the whole phrase; hence, DP. This is a whole different topic.

Can it, therefore, be called a determiner group or is there an actual term for it?

Comment: Maybe you could include some examples and counterexamples?

Comment: Oh. You're right. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe the concept of an **extended projection** in X'-theoretic syntax is helpful here. Within this system, modals and auxilliaries are part of the **verbal extended projection**, and determiners, numerals etc. are part of the **nominal extended projection**. An extended projection consists of a lexical head and the functional structure surrounding the lexical projection. The relevant reference is the work of Jane Grimshaw, see e.g. this paper: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1DtOqeuIhA3ZmE2NDM4ZmQtYjYzZi00ZjRlLTk1NmMtODQxM2NkMTVkMDYw/edit?hl=en_US

Comment: Of course, if you *don't* accept the DP hypothesis, you *could* call these determiner phrases.  (Or, if you accept Huddleston & Pullum's terms, determinative phrases.)

Comment: @snailboat Ah yes...i didn't catch that bit in the question about the DP-hypothesis. To be honest, i don't really see how adopting the DP-hypothesis prevents one from calling these DPs. In fact, i think most people would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A somewhat more useful way is to do what snailboat suggests above,
namely ignore the `DP` Hypothesis, which is after all just a hypothesis that can't be disproved,
and go for something that represents the data rather than the theory.

For instance, McCawley 1998 distinguishes between two types of nouny constituent in English:

1. **`Nʹ`** (pronounced "N-Bar" -- don't ask), which is a phrasal unit headed by an `N`
   and
2. **`NP`** (pronounced "N-P"), which is the syntactic constituent type
   corresponding to the logical type *Argument of Predicate*
   (and thus is outside the X-Bar nodal system).

For instance, it's not clear that the subject of

- *That he arrived late is very unfortunate.*
  (i.e, the complement clause *that he arrived late*,
  which must be a noun phrase since it's the subject),

can be said even to **have** a head, and if so, it's clearly not headed by a noun.
It's simply an NP, since it corresponds to an argument of the predicate adjective *unfortunate*.

The constituent containing determiners that precedes prenominal adjectives
is then simply, in X-Bar terminology, a **`Dʹ`**.  In general, an `NP` will contain a `Dʹ`.
For instance, the subject of the following sentence

- *Quite a few of the more than ten thousand people took his advice.*

would be parsable as [`NP` [`Dʹ` *Quite ...  thousand* `Dʹ`] [N *people* N] NP].

Whether `Dʹ` is actually the same constituent type as `DP`
depends entirely on one's preferred nomenclatural presuppositions.
It doesn't bear on descriptions of phenomena, except to counsel one
to avoid confusing modes of expression; after all, the idea is to be **clear**.

Comment: Upvoted for being very interesting. So if i understand correctly, what you call an 'NP' corresponds to semantic argumenthood? Surely that renders the terminology rather confusing, given that an 'NP' is not necessarily a 'Noun Phrase' (in the sense that it isn't necessarily headed by a noun). Why not just call them arguments? With respect to your example: *"That he arrived late is very unfortunate"*, doesn't this just show us that CPs (or clauses, if you like) can be subjects? I don't see any compelling reason to call it an NP.

Comment: @jawler one further small question - within McCawley's framework, which i'm not really familiar with, what is the distinction between an X' and an XP? *[NP [Dʹ Quite ... thousand Dʹ] [N people N] NP]* wouldn't be a valid X'-theoretic object, since D' labels an intermediate projection, and one can't have an intermediate projection without a maximal projection.

Comment: `NP` is the only logically-based one, and the only one with a P; it's not in the X-Bar system. The only terms in the X-Bar system are (as I quoted them in [Jim's memorial](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf)) "`Nʹ`, `Vʹ`, `Pʹ`, `Aʹ`, `Advʹ`, and `0ʹ` (zero-bar – ‘phrasal unit whose head belongs to no part of speech’); and distinguishing `Nʹ` from `NP` (which is not, like `Nʹ`, a phrase headed by an `N`, but rather is a different type, outside the X-Bar system – `NP` is the syntactic constituent type corresponding to the logical type _Argument of Predicate_)."

Comment: Oh, and maximal projections and their ilk don't occur, either, so that's another thing you don't have to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I really should get around to reading McCawley '98.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to the question is NO, there is no established term such as *determiner group* used to denote the word combinations in the question, and there is a reason why no term has been established to denote such word combinations. This reason is that the relevant words (e.g. *my three*, *both the*, *all the many*) hardly qualify as a unit of syntax. At most, one can acknowledge that they form a *string*.

Such word combinations qualify as a constituent in no theory of syntax (that I am aware of), not in phrase structure grammars and not in dependency grammars. Furthermore, such word combinations do not qaulify as chains, that is, they do not qualify as *catenae*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catena_%28linguistics%29. In contrast, verb predicates (e.g. *will have fixed*, *has been fixed*, *may have been being fixed*) do qualify as chains of words, as catenae. The fact that determiner strings qualify neither as constituents nor as catenae means that it is more difficult to denote such combinations with a particular syntactic term. Theoretical syntax tends to focus on word combinations that are recognizable units.

But there is nothing to stop one from establishing a new term, e.g. *determiner string* or *determiner group*. In fact, since there is no pre-established term for such combinations, one has more freedom to call them whatever one wants.